# Breaking out `.each` loop in `Cypress`

Tags: loops, break, cypress

I have the following code

```
let c = 0
cy.get(selector).each(count => {
   if (++c == count-1)
      break
   //somthing 
})
```

Let's say we have `n` selected DOM objects, and I want to apply some function on only `n-2` objects. Is it possible to do it in Cypress?

Answer (score 12):

As described in the documentation [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/each.html#Return-early), you can just do `return false;` if the condition which should stop the loop is triggered.

```js
let c = 0
cy.get(selector).each(count => {
   if (++c == count-1) return false;
   // loop execution code
})
```

Comment: @AlanYong not the most helpful comment you just left ;) Can you show your code?

Comment: let c = 0
cy.get(selector).each(ele => {
   ele.invoke('text').then(text => {
    if (text === 'some string') return false;
   })
})

Answer (score 1):

showcase - max (count) equals 2.

```
let count = 0;
const max = 2;

cy.get(selector).each((element) => {

if (count == max) return false;

cy.wrap(element).click();

count++;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).